# Pricing a swaption in a Hull-White model with two curves

Tags: swaption, hullwhite, multicurve

Let's say the forward swap rate $s_t$ is equal to $$s_t = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^N \delta_j^{\textrm{float}} P_{t,T_j^{\textrm{float}}}^{\textrm{disc}} L_t^{[T_{j-1}^{\textrm{float}},T_j^{\textrm{float}}]}}{A_t}$$ where the annuity $A_t$ is defined by : $$A_t = \sum_{i=1}^M \delta_j^{\textrm{fixed}} P_{t,T_i^{\textrm{fixed}}}^{\textrm{disc}}$$ and that my swaption's payoff at time $T = T_0^{\textrm{fixed}} = T_0^{\textrm{float}}$ is $A_T \left( s_T - K \right)_{+}$ and finally that I want to price it with Monte-Carlo in a Hull-White model with one or several factors, so that I want to compute

$$\pi_0 = A_0 {\mathbf{E}}^{\mathbf{Q}^A} \left[ \left(s_T - K\right)_{+} \right]$$

where $\mathbf{Q}^A$ is the annuity measure.

The Hull-White model diffuses only the short rate $r_t$ while my swaption's payoff needs two types of zero-coupons :

- the "discounting" forward zero-coupons $P_{T,T_i^{\textrm{fixed}}}^{\textrm{disc}}$ and $P_{T,T_j^{\textrm{float}}}^{\textrm{disc}}$ used to discount in the future cash-flows from a more distant future
- the "forwarding" "theoretical" zero-coupons $P_{T,T_j^{\textrm{float}}}^{\textrm{fwd}}$ defined by $L_t^{[T_{j-1}^{\textrm{float}},T_j^{\textrm{float}}]} \equiv \frac{P_{T,T_{j-1}^{\textrm{float}}}^{\textrm{fwd}} - P_{T,T_j^{\textrm{float}}}^{\textrm{fwd}}}{\delta_j^{\textrm{float}} P_{T,T_j^{\textrm{float}}}^{\textrm{fwd}}}$ used to compute the forward "LIBOR" rates (I am indeed practically interested in ICE swaptions "on" EURIBOR rates)

Are both types of zero-coupons computed through the same diffused short rate $r_t$ or not ? What is done exactly ?